# Añadir fragmento al contenedor con Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Estoy intentando añadir un fragmento al contenedor en caso de que estemos usando un layout dinámico (en este caso pantallas normales y para tablets usar un estático con la disposición de pantalla distinta). Tengo un activity el cual cargara los dos layouts estaticos en caso de caber en pantalla (tablets) y el dinamico con transicion entre los layouts para moviles.
El problema es que cuando intento añadirlo, me indica que la forma de añadirlo esta deprecated `fragmentManager.beginTransaction()`.

Este es mi MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.fragmentos)

        //Comprobamos si estamos usando el layout dinámico
        if(findViewById<View>(R.id.fragment_container) != null){
            //Si se esta restaurando no hace falta cargar el fragmento
            if(savedInstanceState != null) return

            //Creamos el fragmento
            val ppalFragment = PrincipalFragment()

            //Pasamos los extras del intent al fragmento
            ppalFragment.arguments = intent.extras

            //Añadimos el fragmento al contenedor
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, ppalFragment).commit()
        }else{
            //Estatico
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Lo mejor es usar .replace() en lugar de .add() para realizar el reemplazo del Fragment en el contenedor de otra forma puedes ver Fragmentos uno sobre otro, si es solo uno el que siempre vas a agregar esta bien con .add() .

Answer (score 2):

En la documentación puedes ver que la clase [FragmentManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentManager)  es obsoleta desde la API 28, e indica lo siguiente:

> Utilice FragmentManager de la biblioteca de compatibilidad para
> obtener un comportamiento coherente en todos los dispositivos y
> acceder al ciclo de vida.

La [biblioteca de compatibilidad](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library) indica que actualmente usando AndroidX se debe realizar de la siguiente forma (`supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()`):

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
  .replace(R.id.fragment_container, MyFragment.class, null)  
  .commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Adjunto la solución:

```
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragment_container, ppalFragment).commit()
```

Por la opción actual:

```
supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.fragment_container, ppalFragment).commit()
```